# SFTP download in background

Tags: ssh, sftp

1. I am connected locally on machine A.
2. I have connected through a web console on machine B.
3. On B's shell, I have connected through SSH on machine C.
4. On C's shell, I want to execute a remote SFTP download from machine D with an account.
5. Then, I want do shutdown machines A and B while keeping my download remain as it on C machine.

*Note: I don't have any GUI based access.*

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should install `screen` on machine C. Eg:

```
ssh box-c
sudo apt-get install screen
screen
```

You'll be in a new shell

```
scp foo@box-d:somefile .
<ctrl-a><d>
```

You'll see a message about being detached, logout and shut down your other machines. At some point later you can ssh back to box-c and run `screen -r` to reconnect to your shell. Then exit the shell and screen will exit.